# Адресное поле команды

Tags: ассемблер, unix, адрес

Изучаю операционные системы и столкнулась с определением относительной адресации - адрес получается сложением адресного поля команды и адреса самой этой команды.
Все не могу понять, что такое адресное поле команды. Можете пожалуйста объяснить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> адрес получается сложением адресного поля команды и адреса самой этой команды. Все не могу понять, что такое адресное поле команды

Скорей всего подразумевается смещение, просто число, которое является частью команды.

Например команда (в синтаксисе nasm) `jmp $+5` представляется опкодом (на x86) `eb 03`.

`eb` здесь представляет саму операцию, а `03` — операнд, смещение на которое надо совершить прыжок. `03`, а не `05` — это просто особенности синтаксиса ассемблера т.к. он предполагает смещение относительно начала команды, а действия с `IP` выполняются после загрузки команды, откуда и получается разница в 2 байта — длина команды.

Собственно на x86 относительная адресация применяется исключительно в командах перехода, что в принципе и логично: данные так не очень удобно адресовать...